# WPF- Making sunken effect slower for a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button in WPF that creates a sunken effect when the button is clicked. I was wondering is there a property to make the effect appear slower rather than the default speed?

Here is my code:

```
   private void btnEnglish_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            btnEnglish.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Thickness Animation:

```
private void btnEnglish_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ThicknessAnimation myThicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
   myThicknessAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
   myThicknessAnimation.From = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
   myThicknessAnimation.To = new Thickness(10,10,0,0);       

   btnEnglish.BeginAnimation(Button.BorderThicknessProperty, myThicknessAnimation);
}
```

**Edited:**

*Since you want your button to come on back to its default place*

```
private void btnEnglish_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ThicknessAnimation myThicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
   myThicknessAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
   myThicknessAnimation.From = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
   myThicknessAnimation.To = new Thickness(10,10,0,0);
   myThicknessAnimation.AutoReverse = true;

   myThicknessAnimation.Completed += (arg, s) => { btnEnglish.BeginAnimation(Button.BorderThicknessProperty, null); };
   btnEnglish.BeginAnimation(Button.BorderThicknessProperty, myThicknessAnimation);
}
```

Comment: what does this do??

Comment: I don't want it to delay but rather the "effect" move slower if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't go back to original position after click

Comment: So I can remove the btnEnglish.BorderThicknes.......? Since it makes no difference

Comment: Also, it is possible to implement this in XAML?

Comment: Would it be possible to make it sink faster but when it returns to original state, it goes slower?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161495/discussion-between-cookie-monster-and-tabby).

Answer (score 4):

Use Thickness Animation  instead of explicit PreviewMouseDownEvent

refer below sample

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="btnEnglish"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.BorderThickness)" SpeedRatio="1" From="0"
            To="10,10,0,0" Duration="0:0:3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Use AutoReverse="True" to bring back to original state

Comment: So I don't need to use event handler?

Comment: Does duration 0:0:3 means 0.3 sec?