# Setting sunken effect in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set my property in XAML to have a sunken effect when the button is pressed. I do this by increasing the border thickness. 
It gives me an error saying the specific value cannot be assigned. What am I making mistake here?

Note: I tried using the DropShadowEffect and it works but Border effect does not work.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultLanguageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" > <!--BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButton}" >-->
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>

                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Border BorderThickness="5,5,0,0" >

                                            </Border>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource RedBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{DynamicResource NoBorder}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            </Style>
```

Comment: Do you mean to set the `Effect` property of the border? Perhaps you're missing a `TargetName` attribute on your setter.

Comment: Yes i need to set effect

Comment: [This question looks very similar to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749882/how-can-i-set-a-property-of-a-dropshadoweffect-via-a-trigger-in-a-controltemplat)

Comment: It works for dropshadow effect , but not for border thickness

Comment: I have a similar situation in my code, `<Border x:Name="border"..` in a `ControlTemplate`, and then in the `Triggers` I have a `Setter` modifying the `BorderThickness` using the `TargetName` attribute. It works fine, I don't understand why it would not work for you. Can you post the full error?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161510/discussion-between-cookie-monster-and-jack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have your trigger like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5,5,0,0"/>
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Effect" Value="..."/>
</Trigger>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a short example where I change the `BorderThickness` of a `Border` within a `ControlTemplate` through `Triggers`:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="0" Background="Aqua" Width="50" Height="50"/>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image][image]

Excuse the shoddy proportions on those images.

Comment: what about the effect?

Comment: Well if you're trying to set an `Effect` and change the `BorderThickness`, put them both in separate setters.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even allow me to set BorderThickness

Comment: I don't think that works since I can't assign BorderThickness to property

Comment: hey are you there?

Comment: Invite me to discussion chat when u see this

Answer (score 3):

Define style in resources:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SunkenEffectStyle">
 <Style.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
     <EventTrigger.Actions>
       <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" BeginTime="00:00:00">
               <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="10,10,0,0" />
               <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger.Actions>
  </EventTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Style="{StaticResource SunkenEffectStyle}" 
        Height="50" Width="100"/>
```

this answer also covers your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880171/wpf-making-sunken-effect-slower-for-a-button/47880258#47880258)

i have used keyframes here since you wanted animation to be faster at start and slower while returning

[image: Sunken Effect]